# How to control the draw order of overlapping elements with CSS3 rotate3d and transformZ?

Tags: javascript, css

http://staging.isaidicanshout.com/test3d/

I am using CSS3 rotate3D to create a 3D grid of tiles that respond to mouse movement. In safari everything works fine, but in Chrome, the draw order is determined by the order of the code, not the position in z-space. If an element passes in front of an element that should appear behind it, but appears after it in the code, it will be obscured.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `z-index` instead (or as well as)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood your concern is you can use `z-index` css property on your `.tile` elements and give them `position: relative;` for the `z-index` to work properly:

```
.tile {
    float: left;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

On `<div>` tags assign `z-indez` value as desired:

```
<div style="z-index: 4">
```

See working jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jh5etqfk/

Notice img/02.jpg is on top of img/01.jpg and img/03.jpg

NOTE: Images URL are referencing to your site.

Comment: All of the tiles are using the same class, and the z-transform is assigned randomly, so if I set the z-index for the class, it sets the z-index for all of them. in the fiddle you provided, images in front are still appearing behind.

Comment: I made a mistake. Add `position: relative;` to the classes and assign `z-index` in the `<div>` tag. Since you are giving random values you can assign them randomly. See updated answer.

Comment: bingo! adding position to the .tile elements seems to have soled the problem. it's always something simple but not obvious!

Comment: Yes. `z-index` only works on positioned elements, can be `fixed` `relative` or `absolute` but not `static`. Since the default is `position: static;` you just give them `position: relative;` and you are all set :)

Comment: Depends on the version of IE, you may experience problems with the transform property. Position and z-index should work fine. In which version are you aiming to make it work?

Comment: I'm really only interested in having this work on modern browsers. I haven't done any experimenting yet, but it appears not to work in the latest IE or even Firefox, actually.

Comment: Well I am looking at it in Firefox and IE11 and it does work haha

Answer (score 1):

Try using this the `preserve-3d` and `perspective` css values:

```
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1000px;    
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejafj1v5/)

Comment: Yes. If you want the z position to be relevant, use preserve-3d